# Longitude bounds of cartopy.crs.Geodetic

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I was playing around with cartopy, plotting a satellite groundtrack on a PlateCarree map from lat/lon lists, and I noticed that you could give it higher values than 360 degrees. However, it stops plotting between 600 and 700 degrees. I could not find anything in the documentation about that, so I was wondering ...

Quick code to show that : there should be one more leg, from 630 to 720 degrees

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

lon = [-90, 0, 90, 180, 270, 360, 450, 540, 630, 720]
lat = [-10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 55, 60, 65]

ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_global()
ax.plot(lon, lat, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

Thanks !

Comment: Are you asking how to plot the missing part using bad values of longitude? The valid values of `longitude` in degrees are not beyond +-360. You can use `mod` function by 360 to get proper values.

Comment: I was simply curious that you could input longitudes over 360 degrees, but that it stopped plotting them around 600 degrees. Thank you for your answer though !

Comment: No idea on that finding. But I add some reasons about allowing the use of longitude grater than 360 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you treat the values of longitude properly, you will get what you expect. In the snippet code below `numpy.mod()` is used to handle this.

```
 ax.plot(np.mod(lon, 360), lat, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

The plot (with annotation at each vertex):

[image: world_plot]

**Edit**

Q: Why some values of longitude greater than 360 degrees are valid for plotting?

First of all, at prime-meridian (Greenwich meridian) the longitude is 0 or 360 degrees. Usually, one should use the values in the range of 0 to 360 degrees for longitude. However, when plotting a line segment crossing the prime-meridian, say, longitude goes from 359 to 359+2 to new location in the east direction. If the longitude is `mod`, i.e. (359+2)%360 -> 1, the line will go to the west in stead. Thus, value greater than 360 is useful here. Scientists who need to plot  line strings showing polar motion for a period of 100 years would be able to plot them around the north pole without much trouble.

Comment: "*Usually, one should use the values in the range of 0 to 360 degrees for longitude*", isn't longitude [defined between -180 and +180°](https://gisgeography.com/latitude-longitude-coordinates/) instead?